# Sidekiq: change rate of retry for failed job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have jobs of a particular type that I'd like to have retry more frequently than set by the default Sidekiq interval. Is this currently possible? Ideally the job would retry every 5 seconds for up to a minute. Not entirely sure this is currently something that's trivial to plugin to a Sidekiq job.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling you can do this:

```
class Worker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_retry_in do |count|
    5
  end
end
```

Comment: Please notice that `5` is counted in seconds

Answer (score 1):

If you need other range, can use minute syntax

```
sidekiq_retry_in do |_count|
  10.minutes
end
```

Comment: This will work in sidekiq 5 and 7 but not 6 as per https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/issues/5806

Comment: It is true! I did not know this

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering if calling `10.minutes` in the block works, because I can't comment on an answer.

According to the Sidekiq code, you need to pass an Integer, or either  `:kill`  or `:discard` symbols.

`10.minutes` returns an instance of `ActiveSupport::Duration`

This means that the following would work:

```rb
class Worker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_retry_in { 10.minutes.to_i }
end
```

[Source](https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/blob/4c101d243e9589cd3d1a81060dac602beb1652a1/lib/sidekiq/job_retry.rb#L193-L214)

Comment: In sidekiq 7 this has been fixed (https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/issues/5806), durations should now work as before